# Elasticsearch new java API client gives error in bulk operation [jakarta.json.JsonException: Unable to get a JsonProvider]

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api-client

I have elasticsearch 8.6.1 version installed. I'm trying to add data using java API client. Code snippet is :

```
restClient = restClientBuilder.build();
client = new ElasticsearchClient(new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper())); 

// dummy data
Employee emp = new Employee("E01", (short)32, "Sunil Kumar"); 
        
try {
    client.index(i -> i
                    .index("employee")
                    .id(emp.getEmpID())
                    .document(emp));
    } catch (ElasticsearchException | IOException e) {}
```

But while performing basic index operation giving Error:
**Unable to execute bulk request.
co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpMappingException: Error deserializing co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.ShardStatistics: jakarta.json.JsonException: Unable to get
a JsonProvider. Check your classpath or thread context classloader. (JSON path: items[0]._shards.total) (line no=1, column no=155, offset=-1)**

Following are depedency jars in classpath:

1. elasticsearch-java-8.6.2.jar
2. jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar
3. jakarta.json-api-2.0.1.jar

Please help on how it can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. The way to solve the problem is to add the provider classes implementation library. As explained here https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/pull/63 an implementation of provider class is Eclipse Parsson. So adding the dependency of provider implementation 'org.eclipse.parsson:parsson:1.1.1' and the api interface 'jakarta.json:jakarta.json-api:2.1.1' is a working solution.